# Looping through a list to append and remove <span> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling the server every 5 secs to get the data, then looping through my list and appending a "span" with the right data to my list. The problem is i can't make the "span" dissapear when data returned from the server is empty, except when i use "fadeOut()" on the "span". But then i can't calculate the right sum of all the "li span" (countCont() ), since they are still appended to the DOM and have a value. 
So what i would like to do is remove the respective "li span" if data returned from the server that is assigned to it is empty, so i can calculate the right sum.
Here is how i assign data to my list:

```
     $.get(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, info) {
          $("#accordion li").text(function (y, name) {
            if ($(this).is(":contains(" + info.cName + ")")) {
                if ($(this).is(":has(span)")) {
                    $(this).children().replaceWith('<span class = "cCount">' + info.count + '</span>');
                    $(this).children().fadeOut(10000);
                } else {
                    $(this).append('<span class = "cCount">' + info.count + '</span>');
                }
             }

             countCont($(this).parent().attr('id'));
          });
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you fade it out, remove it from the DOM using [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
//...
$("#accordion li").text(function (y, name) {
   var $this = $(this); //also store this, dont select it 5 times

   if ($this.is(":contains(" + info.cName + ")")) {
      if ($this.is(":has(span)")) {
         $this.children().replaceWith('<span class = "cCount">' + info.count + '</span>');
         $this.children().fadeOut(10000);
         $this.remove();
      } else {
         $this.append('<span class = "cCount">' + info.count + '</span>');
      }
   }
   countCont($this.parent().attr('id'));
});
```

**Edit:** In response to the comment, this will remove the span if it exists then add a new one on:

```
//...

var $this = $(this); //also store this, dont select it 5 times

if ($this.is(":contains(" + info.cName + ")")) {
   if ($this.is(":has(span)")) {
      //remove the span
      var $span = $('span', this);
      $span.fadeOut(10000);
      $span.remove();
   }
   //always append new span
   $this.append('<span class = "cCount">' + info.count + '</span>');
}
```

Comment: I only want to remove the "li span", not the entire li. I tried remove() before asking here aswell. The behaviour i get is that fadeOut() is no longer activated, instead the "span" is removed after the first $.get, then appended again at the second $.get and so on..

Comment: @pitic to remove and add a new span, do just that. Code updated to reflect.

Comment: Thanks, but i still get the same behaviour.

Comment: That's because the code makes sure there is always a span there, never do you remove one and then don't add another span in its place, so the count can only go up. You will have to do a check on the data you retrieve to see if you want to add another span instead of always doing it.

Comment: I added a check on the data and then faded out all the spans in my list att the same time, that seemed to do the trick. I only change the text in the existing span if the data changes now, works better imo. Thanks for the help. I'll accept ur answer as correct, cause your code is better-looking :)